# Java Integrated Application about Loops and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

***The question is as the following:***

In the game of Nim, two players alternately take marbles from a pile. In 
each move, a player chooses how many marbles to take. The player 
must take at least one but at most half of the marble. Then the other 
player takes a turn. The palyer who takes the last marble loses.

Write a program in which two players play against each other. The 
program first prompts the players to input the initial size (range: 10 ~100 
inclusive) of the pile of marbles. Then, the two players take turns to input 
the number of marbles to take. The program should print the number of 
marbles left after each turn. The game stops when one marble is left in 
the pile. Winning message should be print to indicate who the winner is 
after the game finishes. You could assume the players always input a 
number in correct range. After you finish the program, you could 
actually play this game with your neighbor.

---

***The sample is like this:***

```
Initial no. of marbles [10 ~ 100]: 15
Player1 [1 ~ 7]: 6
Remaining no. of marbles: 9
Player2 [1 ~ 4]: 4
Remaining no. of marbles: 5
Player1 [1 ~ 2]: 2
Remaining no. of marbles: 3
Player2 [1 ~ 1]: 1
Remaining no. of marbles: 2
Player1 [1 ~ 1]: 1
Remaining no. of marbles: 1
Player2 takes the last marble.
Player1 wins!
```

---

***Here's my personal attempt (unfinished):***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhoTakesTheLastMarble {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);       
    System.out.print("Intial no. of marbles [10 ~ 100]: ");
    int n1 = in.nextInt();  
    int[] x = new int[91];
    for (int i = 10; i<=100; i++) {
        x[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Plyaer1 [1 ~ " +(n1/2) +"]:");
    int n2 = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Remaining no. of marbles: " +(n1-n2));
    int n3 = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Player2 [1 ~ " +(n3/2) +"]: ");
    int n4 = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Remaining no. of marbles: " +(n3-n4));

}       

}
```

---

The problem that I'm facing is how to apply for-loop/while-loop into the whole thing so that they can repeat again and again until ***(remaining no. of marbles: 1)***?

Can anyone please spend a five to ten minutes to help me tackle with this problem and teach me your way of solving this problem? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while`-loop to see if marbles are left. You may also want to store the active player so you can use the same code for both players turns.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by TheConstrcutor for http://stackoverflow.com/q/24981670/1266906
 */
public class WhoTakesTheLastMarble {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Initial no. of marbles [10 ~ 100]: ");
        int numberOfMarbles = in.nextInt();

        int activePlayer = 1;
        while (numberOfMarbles > 1) {
            System.out.print("Player" + activePlayer + " [1 ~ " + (numberOfMarbles / 2) + "]: ");
            int taken = in.nextInt();
            numberOfMarbles -= taken;
            System.out.println("Remaining no. of marbles: " + numberOfMarbles);

            if (activePlayer == 1) {
                activePlayer = 2;
            } else {
                activePlayer = 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Player" + activePlayer + " takes the last marble.");
        if (activePlayer == 1) {
            activePlayer = 2;
        } else {
            activePlayer = 1;
        }
        System.out.println("Player" + activePlayer + " wins!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that if there is an error appeared in line 8 (counting from  below) named "Unresolved compilation problem: Unreachable code" for the variable "activePlayer". What does that mean and how to eliminate it?

Comment: @user3865063 that would mean that a condition can never be fulfilled or a method is always exited before certain code is reach and thus the code in question will never get executed. As I did not get this message I would assume that you have a typo and don't assign 1 and 2 in turns to activePlayer

Comment: @user3865063 in the comment you have `while(true)` without a `break` which means that the code after `while` will never run. Change to `while(n1 > 1)` and it should work.

Comment: I've edited your answer into my version. The only difference is the variables: numOfMarbles -> n1; taken -> n2; activePlayer -> pn

Comment: @user3865063 as I said 2 minutes ago: `while(true)` will loop forever. Change it to `while(n1 > 1)`

Comment: But while(n1 > 1) means nothing actually. It's just used to replace (true) but it won't loop forever. Am I right?

Comment: It means loop until `n1` is less than or equal to 1. And as you reduce n1 it means that your game will finish one day.